# How to order terms in a polynomial in two variables negative lexicographically

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials

I have several polynomials in variables p and q, each term in which has total degree n, a constant. I would like to output the polynomial in increasing powers of p (and hence decreasing powers of q), and within each term I would like the factors to be in alphabetical order, i.e. the power of p followed by the power of q.

For example, I would like 2p q + p^2 to be displayed exactly like that. (Or preferably, with the powers as superscripts, but this is not so important.)

Everything I try yields p^2 + 2p q instead.
I have tried TraditionalForm, PolynomialForm, and these answers:

[How to reorder and combine terms in a polynomial with multi-variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96377/how-to-reorder-and-combine-terms-in-a-polynomial-with-multi-variables)

[How do I disable that Mathematica orders terms in lexicographic order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105248/how-do-i-disable-that-mathematica-orders-terms-in-lexicographic-order)

[How to simplify a polynomial and get the results in the order that I want?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45725/how-to-simplify-a-polynomial-and-get-the-results-in-the-order-that-i-want)

[How can I reorder the factors in the terms of a polynomial?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30216/how-can-i-reorder-the-factors-in-the-terms-of-a-polynomial)

I am using Mathematica version 9.

Comment: Is it only for display purposes that you want this? Or something more?

Comment: Only for display purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Fixing the `+-` Problem**

```
displayPolynomial[poly_] := Block[{Plus},
  DisplayForm@ToBoxes[
    Plus @@ MonomialList[poly, {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}]
   ] /. {a___, "+", RowBox[{"-", b_}], c___} :> {a, RowBox[{"-\[ThinSpace]", b}], c}
 ]
poly = 2 p q + p^2 - q^3 - q^7 + p^2 q^3
displayPolynomial[poly]
```

[image]

or

```
displayPolynomial[poly_] := Module[{expr},
   Unprotect[Plus]; ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless];
   expr = DisplayForm@ToBoxes[Plus @@ MonomialList[poly, {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}]];
   SetAttributes[Plus, Orderless]; Protect[Plus];
   expr
  ]
```

**Nicer Version**

```
displayPolynomial[poly_] :=
  Block[{Plus}, DisplayForm@ToBoxes[Plus @@ MonomialList[poly, {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}]]]
poly = 2 p q + p^2 + q^3 + q^7 + p^2 q^3
displayPolynomial[poly]
```

[image]

The important part here is the second argument of `MonomialList`, which specifies the ordering. See the [documentation page for `PolynomialOrdering`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PolynomialOrderings.html).

**Original Version**

As long as there are only two variables, I believe this should work:

```
displayPolynomial[poly_] :=
  DisplayForm@RowBox[ToBoxes /@ Riffle[MonomialList[poly, {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}], "+"]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In the end I adapted your code to this: DisplayForm[RowBox[Map[ToBoxes, 
   Riffle[MonomialList[g[p, q], {p, q}, {{-1, 0}, {0, 0}}], "+"]]]], which works in my particular case, because the order depends only on the power of p, and also all the coefficients are non-negative. Is there a way to avoid the output "+-" in the more general case where you have negative coefficients ?

Comment: @Simon. See the updated versions.

Comment: Thank you very much again. Now using "Module" version of your code. Works perfectly. Changed the matrix to {{-1,0},{0,0}} to suit my needs. Also found that I needed to specify explicitly to MonomialList that the variables are p and q, in order to avoid error messages when poly = p^2, for example. My final adaptation looks like this: displayPolynomial[poly_] := Module[{expr},
  Unprotect[Plus];
  ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless];
  expr = DisplayForm[
    ToBoxes[Apply[Plus, 
      MonomialList[poly, {p, q}, {{-1, 0}, {0, 0}}]]]];
  SetAttributes[Plus, Orderless];
  Protect[Plus];
  expr
  ]

Comment: @Simon. Great! Yeah, I wasn't sure about the correct ordering exactly, but I figured drawing attention to the third argument to `MonomialList` would help. Glad it worked!