# How to sort a "+" sequence and get back a new sequence of "+" sorted?

Tags: sorting

How to sort a "+" sequence like

`1+5+3+2+4`

to get back

`1+2+3+4+5`

Same sorting problem with polynoms (but I am mainly interested in the above simple "1+5+3+2+4" sorting):

`Expand[(x^3 - x + 5)^6]`

`TraditionalForm[Expand[(x^3 - x + 5)^6]]`

`Expand[(x^3 - a*x + 5)^6]`

`Collect[Expand[(x^3 - a*x + b)^6], x, Factor]`

`TraditionalForm[Collect[Expand[(x^3 - a*x + b)^6], x, Factor]]`

Thank you beforehand for an answer.

Regards.

Gianni

Comment: Can you please provide more concrete example for ``1+5+3+2+4``? This obviously gets evaluated to 15. Are you using inactivated operators? In that case: ``Sort@Inactivate[1 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 4, Plus]`` does the job. As for the polynomials: they are sorted by the descending power of $x$. How would you want them to be sorted? By the prefactors?

Comment: `Plus` has the attribute `Orderless`, which means that terms are automatically sorted into canonical order.

Comment: Some possibly related links may be found here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108147/how-to-order-terms-in-a-polynomial-in-two-variables-negative-lexicographically

Answer (score 0):

```
sum="{14+5+9+7}";a=ToString[Sort[ToExpression[StringReplace[sum,"+"->","]]]];
a=StringReplace[a,", "->"+"];
a=StringReplace[a,"{"->""];
a=StringReplace[a,"}"->""]
```

a sequence 14+5+9+7
is sorted 5+7+9+14

This code can be used or developed in a polynome with variable x.