# How to preserve the order of expressions in the asymptotic expansion?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, asymptotics

I have a complicated expression involving logarithms.

```
 ex = (1/2)*(-4*n + n^2 - n*Log[4] + 4*n*Log[n] - 2*n*Log[n - n/(2*Log[n])] + (-1 + 2*n)*Log[1 + n - 2*Log[n]] - 2*n*Log[Log[n]] + (1/Log[n])*n*(1 + Log[4] + Log[n - n/(2*Log[n])] - (1 + n)*Log[1 + n - 2*Log[n]] + 2*Log[Log[n]]) - Log[(Pi*(-1 + 2*Log[n]))/(2*Log[n]^2)]);
```

I wanted to determine the asymptotic expansion **in order of the weight** of each term.
Unfortunately, `Asymptotic` command is only reasonably usable up to level 1.

```
 Asymptotic[ex, n -> Infinity]
 (* 2 n Log[n] *)
```

If I add `SeriesTermGoal -> 2`, the result is completely unusable.

```
 Asymptotic[ex, n -> Infinity, SeriesTermGoal -> 2]
```

The problem can be easily solved by the following procedure with repeated use of the `Asymptotic` as we successively subtract partial results.

```
 asylog[f_, steps_] := (asyp = 0; Do[asyp += Asymptotic[f - asyp, n -> Infinity];, {j, 1, steps}]; asyp);
```

But Mathematica rearranges the result into a form where the new order of the terms no longer corresponds to their weights.

```
 asylog[ex, 4]
 (* -n - 1/2 n Log[4] + 2 n Log[n] - n Log[Log[n]] + (n Log[Log[n]])/Log[n] *)
```

I can work around this by storing the partial results in an auxiliary field where they are in the correct order (as appropriate for publishing).

```
 asylog2[f_, steps_] := (asyp = 0; asypub = {}; 
 Do[asyp1 = Asymptotic[f - asyp, n -> Infinity]; 
 asypub = Join[asypub, {asyp1}]; asyp += asyp1;, {j, 1, steps}]; 
 asypub);

 asylog2[ex, 4]
 (* {2 n Log[n], -n Log[Log[n]], -n - 1/2 n Log[4], (n Log[Log[n]])/Log[n]} *)
```

This is already usable, albeit with additional manual work.

Unfortunately, if I use `Total[%]` for the previous list, the terms order is again 3124 instead of the desired 1234.

```
 Total[%]
 (* -n - 1/2 n Log[4] + 2 n Log[n] - n Log[Log[n]] + (n Log[Log[n]])/Log[n] *)
```

The question is: how to get the result with the expressions in the right order ?
And ideally can't it directly do the `Asymptotic` command with some parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only answer the title of your question regarding the preservation of order, for which there are already several questions on this site. Working upon the [answer from @march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108158/75628), you can use the following:

```
sumTerms[res_] := 
 Block[{Plus}, 
  DisplayForm@
    ToBoxes[Plus @@ res] //. {a___, "+", 
     RowBox[{(RowBox[{"-", x___}] | "-"), b___}], c___} :> {a, 
     RowBox[{"-\[ThinSpace]", x, b}], c}
  ]

terms = asylog2[ex, 8];
sumTerms[terms]
```

[image: Summation]

Comment: So the code is very unreadable, but it solves exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First you might simplify your code using `NestList`

```
erg = NestList[# + Asymptotic[ex - # , n -> Infinity] &,Asymptotic[ex, n -> Infinity] , 4]

(*{2 n Log[n], 2 n Log[n] - n Log[Log[n]], 
-n - 1/2 n Log[4] + 2 n Log[n] -n Log[Log[n]], -n - 1/2 n Log[4] + 2 n Log[n] - n Log[Log[n]] + (n Log[Log[n]])/Log[n], 
-n - 1/2 n Log[4] + n/(2 Log[n]) + (n Log[4])/(2 Log[n]) + 2 nLog[n] - n Log[Log[n]] + (n Log[Log[n]])/Log[n]}
*)
```

which gives a list of asymptotic approximations.

Assuming an orderd list we now filter out successively the leading terms

```
fn[0] = 0;
Do[fn[k] = (erg - fn[k - 1])[[k]], {k, 1, 4}] 
res=Table[fn[k], {k, 1, 4}]
(*{2 n Log[n], -n Log[Log[n]], -n - 1/2 n Log[4] +2 n Log[n], -n Log[Log[n]] + (n Log[Log[n]])/Log[n]}*)
```

Accumulation of the result `res` gives the list `erg` of asymptodes!

**final solution**

```
asy2[expr_, iter_ : 3] :=NestList[{Asymptotic[expr - #[[2 ]], n ->Infinity], #[[2 ]] +Asymptotic[expr - #[[2 ]] , n -> Infinity]} &, {Asymptotic[expr, n -> Infinity], Asymptotic[expr, n -> Infinity]} , iter]
```

Function gives a list containing `{{a[k+1]-a[k], a[k+1]},...}'
First entry shows the change between sukcessive iterations and gives the ordered list of asymptotic approximation!

```
asy2[ex, 3][[All, 1]]
(*{2 n Log[n], -n Log[Log[n]], -n - 1/2 n Log[4], (n Log[Log[n]])/Log[n]}*)
```

Comment: Thanks, but again this requires a bit of manual work if I want to publish or move the result somewhere. Code by "Domen" gives a result that can be directly copied without modification.

Comment: You only have to define max order you are interested in .